# Is it possible to use Kivy widgets outside the app window?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, touch

I'm trying to transition a workflow away from a Windows device and into a mobile OS, and to facilitate this I'm starting with moving to a touch screen device running Windows 10. The built-in on-screen keyboard doesn't work well with the existing app, which was written for use with a physical keyboard. I need a keyboard that can toggle quickly between three different layouts, can be easily dragged around the screen and resized if necessary, and can't be easily closed. Kivy seemed like a good start.

I took one look at Kivy's built in keyboard and it already had a lot of the options I needed out of the box plus a lot of power to get the rest going, but when I spun it up in a test with the following code,

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.vkeyboard import VKeyboard

class Test(VKeyboard):
    player = VKeyboard()
    VKeyboard.docked = False

class VkeyboardApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    VkeyboardApp().run()
```

I got a keyboard that was trapped inside an app window and thus couldn't be easily be used with an already existing app. Is it possible to skip the confines of an app window for a widget? Or is this simply the wrong tool for the job?